# Double Integrals - Region delimited by triangle in counterclockwise

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

A triangle with vertices (0,0), (0,1) and (1,2), counterclockwise, delimits a region. Determine an integral over this region of the following expression:
$$\int_{\Omega}(x-y)dx+e^{x+y}dy$$
This kind of exercises fit the line integral, but I don't know how to start solving it, I thought I'd use Green's Theorem. The key is to integrate x first, then y.
$$\int_{\Omega}(x-y)dx+e^{x+y}dy=\int_{\Omega}\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{x+y}) - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)\right]\,dx\,dy =\int_{\Omega}\left[e^{x+y} +1\right]\,dx\,dy $$

What would the extremes of integration look like? I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By green’s theorem, we can convert our line integral (which would require 3 integrals to solve) into a single double integral.

So far, your setup is correct, where we have $$\int_{\Omega}\left[e^{x+y} +1\right]\,dx\,dy$$ over the region(in green)

[image]

We can set up our double integral bounds then to be $$\int_0^1      \int_{2x}^{x+1}        e^{x+y}+1\,dydx$$

Now all that is left is to evaluate the double integral, which should be pretty easy.

---

to set up bounds, we'll use the arrow and shadow method. Choose the $y$ axis first and draw arrows from $y=-\infty$ to $y=\infty$, and see what function the arrow passes through and exits from.

[image]

It passes through the yellow($2x$) first, and then exits purple($x+1$). Those are our y bounds. Now shine a light from $y=\pm\infty$ and see what shadow the region casts on the $x$ axis. This is just the interval $[0, 1]$. Those are our $x$ bounds.

Comment: Could you explain to me how the extremes were defined? And how do I get to the answer, after performing the integrations "$$e^{3}/6− e/2 +5/6.$$

Comment: @Skye https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/digeneralregion.aspx If you're trying to do green's theorem and line integrals without knowing how to set up double integration bounds... then maybe you should review that first 

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @Skye ive added it i guess to the post

Comment: also @Skye if this has answered your question feel free to accept it :)

Comment: I'll accept, I think I made a mistake writing the integration, the correct one would be $$e^{x+y}-1$$

Comment: @Skye No i think you wrote the theorem wrong. Green's theorem says $$\oint_C P\text{ d}x+Q\text{ d}y=\iint_D\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\text{ d}A$$ so your original expression should be right with the +